# Imprimir div con estilos en JS

Tags: javascript, div, function, imprimir

Buenas tardes amigos de la comunidad, hoy vengo con una duda que espero puedan ayudarme a resolver, resulta que quiero imprimir un div con JS pero al momento de mandar los parámetros en la función los estilos no los respeta y el archivo queda hecho un desastre. quiero que el archivo que se imprimirá se abra en otra pestaña y mantenga los estilos. Solo he logrado hacer que el documento se abra en otra pestaña pero no mantiene los estilos, alguien ayúdeme por favor, se los agradeceré mucho. Así se ve la página web y Así se ve el documento:[image: así se ve la página web][image: así se ve el documento]

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function printDiv() {
          var objeto=document.getElementById('imprimir');  //obtenemos el objeto a imprimir
          var ventana=window.open('','_blank');  //abrimos una ventana vacía nueva
          ventana.document.write(objeto.innerHTML);  //imprimimos el HTML del objeto en la nueva ventana
          ventana.document.close();  //cerramos el documento
          ventana.print();  //imprimimos la ventana
          ventana.close();  //cerramos la ventana
        }
    </script>
```

Este es el div que deseo Imprimir

```
<div class="imprimir" id="imprimir">
                    <div class="titulo">HOJA DE SERVICIOS INFORMATICOS</div>
                    <table>
                         <tr>
                            <th>
                                <font style=" text-decoration: underline;">DATOS DEL USUARIO</font><br>
                                <strong>Usuario: </strong><br>
                                <strong>Nombre del Responsable: </strong><br>
                                <strong>Proveedor del Servicio: </strong><br>
                                <strong>Área Solicitante: </strong><br>
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <font style=" text-decoration: underline;">DATOS DEL REPORTE</font><br>
                                <strong>Número de Orden: </strong><br>
                                <strong>Fecha de Registro: </strong><br>
                                <strong>Hora de Registro: </strong><br>
                                <strong>Reportó: </strong><br>
                            </th>
                         </tr>                              
                        <tr>
                            <th>

                                <font style=" text-decoration: underline;">CARACTERÍSTICAS DEL EQUIPO</font><br>
                                <strong>Marca: </strong>
                                <strong>Modelo: </strong><br>
                                <strong>Número de Serie: </strong>
                                <strong>Inventario: </strong><br>
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <font style=" text-decoration: underline;">DESCRIPCIÓN DE LA FALLA O PROBLEMA</font><br>
                                <strong>Descripción detallada del problema: </strong> <br>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                <font style=" text-decoration: underline;">STATUS GENERAL</font><br>
                                <strong>Estado del Reporte: </strong><br>
                                <strong>¿El problema tuvo solución?: </strong><font style="text-transform: uppercase;"></font><br>
                                <strong>Fecha de Finalización: </strong><br>
                                <strong>Hora de Finalización: </strong><br>
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <font style=" text-decoration: underline;">ACTIVIDADES</font><br>
                                <strong>Actividad realizada: </strong><br><br>
                                <strong>Nombre del Prestador de Servicio: </strong><br>
                            </th>
                        </tr>                       
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                <font style=" text-decoration: underline;">EVALUACIÓN DEL SERVICIO</font><br>
                                <strong>La Calidad del Servicio Otorgado por el Departamento de Soporte Técnico fue: </strong>
                                <br>
                                <strong>El Nivel de Atención Otorgado por el Departamento de Soporte Técnico fue: </strong>
                                <br>
                                <strong>El Nivel Profesional para que el Departamento de Soporte Técnico solucionará el problema fue: </strong>
                                <br>
                                <strong>El Tiempo de Respuesta en que el Departamento de Soporte Técnico lo atendió fue: </strong>
                                <br>
                                <strong>Evaluación General del Reporte: </strong>

                            </th>
                        </tr>

                    </table>
                    <div class="firma">________________________________________<br>FIRMA DE CONFORMIDAD DEL USUARIO
                    </div>                  
                </div>
```

Esto es de los estilos, es muy poco el estilo que contiene la página:

```
.imprimir{
    background: white;
    margin-right: 200px;
    margin-left: 200px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    max-width: 1000px;
}
.imprimir table{
    max-width: 960px;
}
```

Comment: podrias poner el div que quieres imprimir , para hacer pruebas @Harrison Olvera.

Comment: Por favor coloca el archivo html del cual extraes el div

Comment: Listo he colocado el div, ese lo comenté sin datos por qué lo relleno con consultas de PHP y MySQL... espero puedan ayudarme, igual en la imagen se nota el estilo que tiene en HTML

Comment: estas usando bootstrap también para el estilo?

Comment: @SebastiánLagosYañez estoy usando Materialize pero eso no debe prohibir nada en cuanto al estilo nativo que yo le programé en CSS

Answer (score 1):

Tiene que ver con los estilos del html al momento de imprimir, lo que deberías hacer es agregarle el atributo `media="all"` a los estilos así incorpora a cuando alguien quiere imprimir, por ejemplo:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mis_estilos.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

Si quieres tener estilos específicos, distintos a los que se muestra en la página, puedes crear otro archivo `.css` y luego agregarlo con el atributo `media="print"`.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mis_estilos_imprimir.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

---

Otra forma es mediante los media query de `.css`, por ejemplo:

#### mis_estilos.css

```
@media print {
  .elemento {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .otro_elemento {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: Kleith intentaré como me dices amigo, veré como me va, muchas gracias

Comment: no funcionó con ninguna de las opciones que me has proporcionado :/

Comment: ponte el css en la pregunta @HarrisonOlvera

Answer (score 0):

Mira hice algunas pruebas y para que funcione el estilo debe estar dentro del div que quieres imprimir

```js
 function printDiv() {
          var objeto=document.getElementById('imprimir'); 
   
   //obtenemos el objeto a imprimir
          var ventana=window.open('','_blank');  //abrimos una ventana vacía nueva
          ventana.document.write(objeto.innerHTML);  //imprimimos el HTML del objeto en la nueva ventana
          ventana.document.close();  //cerramos el documento
          ventana.print();  //imprimimos la ventana
          ventana.close();  //cerramos la ventana
        }
```

```css
.imprimir{
    background: white;
    margin-right: 200px;
    margin-left: 200px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    max-width: 1000px;
}
.imprimir table{
    max-width: 960px;
}
```

```html
<div class="imprimir" id="imprimir">
  <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css" media="print">

  <div class="titulo">HOJA DE SERVICIOS INFORMATICOS</div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <font style=" text-decoration: underline;">DATOS DEL USUARIO</font><br>
        <strong>Usuario: </strong><br>
        <strong>Nombre del Responsable: </strong><br>
        <strong>Proveedor del Servicio: </strong><br>
        <strong>Área Solicitante: </strong><br>
      </th>
      <th>
        <font style=" text-decoration: underline;">DATOS DEL REPORTE</font><br>
        <strong>Número de Orden: </strong><br>
        <strong>Fecha de Registro: </strong><br>
        <strong>Hora de Registro: </strong><br>
        <strong>Reportó: </strong><br>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>

        <font style=" text-decoration: underline;">CARACTERÍSTICAS DEL EQUIPO</font><br>
        <strong>Marca: </strong>
        <strong>Modelo: </strong><br>
        <strong>Número de Serie: </strong>
        <strong>Inventario: </strong><br>
      </th>
      <th>
        <font style=" text-decoration: underline;">DESCRIPCIÓN DE LA FALLA O PROBLEMA</font><br>
        <strong>Descripción detallada del problema: </strong> <br>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <font style=" text-decoration: underline;">STATUS GENERAL</font><br>
        <strong>Estado del Reporte: </strong><br>
        <strong>¿El problema tuvo solución?: </strong>
        <font style="text-transform: uppercase;"></font><br>
        <strong>Fecha de Finalización: </strong><br>
        <strong>Hora de Finalización: </strong><br>
      </th>
      <th>
        <font style=" text-decoration: underline;">ACTIVIDADES</font><br>
        <strong>Actividad realizada: </strong><br><br>
        <strong>Nombre del Prestador de Servicio: </strong><br>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <font style=" text-decoration: underline;">EVALUACIÓN DEL SERVICIO</font><br>
        <strong>La Calidad del Servicio Otorgado por el Departamento de Soporte Técnico fue: </strong>
        <br>
        <strong>El Nivel de Atención Otorgado por el Departamento de Soporte Técnico fue: </strong>
        <br>
        <strong>El Nivel Profesional para que el Departamento de Soporte Técnico solucionará el problema fue: </strong>
        <br>
        <strong>El Tiempo de Respuesta en que el Departamento de Soporte Técnico lo atendió fue: </strong>
        <br>
        <strong>Evaluación General del Reporte: </strong>

      </th>
    </tr>

  </table>
  <div class="firma">________________________________________<br>FIRMA DE CONFORMIDAD DEL USUARIO
  </div>
</div>

<button onclick="printDiv()">Imrpimir</button>
```

Lo que hice fue que puse un estilo dentro , el que está dentro del div tiene por `media="print"`

> PD: Pruébalo en tus archivos para que funcione ya que aca no me toma
>   bién el snippet, pero lo probe en otro lado y me funciona

Comment: @HarrisonOlvera mira este ejemplo si te funciona.

Comment: muchas gracias, revisaré tu código amigo, te aviso si resulta